# Cannot ssh to the remote server from my local computer Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: 18.04, server, permissions, ssh

I changed my remote server ssh port from 22 to 2222 and after that I restarted the server and now i cannot ssh to my server. it always gives me `Permission denied (publickey)`

I use `ssh root@MY.IP.HERE gives that`
I also use `ssh -p 2222 root@MY.IP.HERE gives that`

it gives me `ssh: connect to host MY.IP port 2222: Connection refused`

what is the problem here?
Basically i cannot login to my server to change any file!

I searched a lot and I found lots of answers on this topic but they always try to change some file on remote server, which in my case I can't even ssh to my server to change any thing?
what can I Do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to stackexchange:askubuntu! You have successfully locked yourself out of your server. You need to contact the system operator, or possibly they have an administrative backend where you can boot into a rescue system and change the offending configuration. The file you were, most likely, told to edit is the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file – where a pubkey line for your host should be placed. You could also change /etc/ssh/sshd_config and make sure there's a line

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Which is now reading "no" - which forces the pubkey authentication, which is *much* more secure!

Comment: thank you very much, i would contact my system operator!